# How to add the image file from camera to to the path File i created

Tags: java, android

Okay, I have been looking for a way around this, I capture an image from camera or gallery and also created an image file path but unfortunately I can get the image because the image from the camera or gallery isn't in the created file path actually. So how can I solve this?

I really don't know what to say here but I am sure I have tried all I could to fix this but I'm in a blackout right now.

```
// function for the createdImageFile....
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
```

how can I put the image received into this path actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to get the URI from the taken picture. 
In order to pick an image from the gallery and from camera, you could try this way :

1) This method for pick an image from gallery

```
private void pickFromGallery(int galleryCode) {
    URI_REQUEST_CODE = galleryCode;
    Intent intent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

2) This method to get an image taken with the camera (be sure to replace "com.your.package.name" with your package name)

```
//declare a global variable in your scope to provide the URI of image taken with camera
private URI uri;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int captureCode) {
    URI_REQUEST_CODE = captureCode;
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.your.package.name",
                    photoFile);
            uri = photoURI;
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Build the onActivityResult method

```
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // Result code is RESULT_OK only if the user selects an Image
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    if (URI_REQUEST_CODE == 1) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        if (selectedImage != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("UriFromGalleryPicture", "onActivityResult: " + selectedImage.toString());
                        }
                    } else if (URI_REQUEST_CODE == 2) {
                        if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(this)) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("UriFromCameraPicture", "onActivityResult: " + uri);
                    }
                }
```

4) Call pickFromGallery(1) / dispatchTakePictureIntent(2) methods where you need the image URI

Let us know if this helped, you should add the error you get in detail inside your question, and the path generated for the image